# How do I declare a conditional that includes "or" on the command line?

Tags: bash, if-statement, command, line

I'm trying to write an if/then statement on the command line that takes two conditions.  I can't seem to get the syntax right.  I've tried:

```
if [ "$var1" == "value1" || "$var2" == "value2"]; 
if [ "$var1" == "value1"] || ["$var2" == "value2"]; 
if [[ "$var1" == "value1" || "$var2" == "value2"]];
```

All return errors.  I know it's a basic question but I'm still fairly new to command line scripting.  Any help is welcome.

Comment: `if [[ "$var1" == "value1" || "$var2" == "value2" ]]; then : fi;` should work

Comment: I'm still getting errors. Does the "then : fi;" have to be on the same line or something?  This is the error: "syntax error near `;'" and then it specifies the line of code.

Comment: See below answer from @chepner

Comment: Add a `;` before `fi`.

Comment: Add output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` to your question.

Comment: You need to have space before ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ "$var1" == "value1" || "$var2" == "value2"];
```

No. `[` does not support the `||` operator.

```
if [ "$var1" == "value1"] || ["$var2" == "value2"];
```

Almost. Use `=`, not `==` with `[`, since POSIX doesn't define `==`. Some shells may support it as an extension though. The error is not including a space before the closing `]`.

```
if [[ "$var1" == "value1" || "$var2" == "value2"]];
```

Yes, but with the same error as above. You need a space before the closing `]]`. The correct line is one of

```
if [ "$var1" = "value1" ] || [ "$var2" = "value2" ];
if [[ "$var1" == "value1" || "$var2" == "value2" ]];
```

Comment: Thanks for being thorough in your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The `test` command (`[ ... ]` syntax) supports the `-o` operator to evaluate a logical-or condition:

```
if [ "$var1" = "value1" -o "$var2" = "value2" ] ; then
    echo match
else
    echo fail
fi
```